# Azure Iot Hub custom protocol gateway for tcp connections

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am pretty new to azure iot hub,our devices are not mqtt compliant and they send telemetry using simple tcp. I have seen other questions regarding tcp for gateway and we can customize the implementation.

The sample implementation is in C#. My question is whether it is possible to implement a custom gateway in node.js or java, which can comprise of all the functionalities like device authentication, device provisioning etc.

I have found iot sdk for node(https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node) but I am not sure whether there are limitations to it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Azure IoT Edge as a gateway to complete Identity translation and protocol translate.

[image]

Ref: [How an IoT Edge device can be used as a gateway - preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-as-gateway)

Comment: If you have used this Azure IoT Edge gateway as a identity translation and protocol translation, can you please share the documentation regarding it. And some working examples. The link you have mentioned above is just a theory. Please share a full detail documentation and working example.

Answer (score -1):

The IoT Hub SDKs all offer broadly the same set of features. Each SDK publishes a feature matrix that you can use to check if the specific feature(s) you require are supported:

- [Node feature matrix](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/master/feature_matrix.md)
- [Java feature matrix](https://github.com/azure/azure-iot-sdk-java#key-features-and-roadmap)
- [.NET feature
  matrix](https://github.com/azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp#key-features-and-roadmap)
- [C feature matrix](https://github.com/azure/azure-iot-sdk-c#key-features-and-roadmap)
- [Python feature matrix](https://github.com/azure/azure-iot-sdk-python#key-features-and-roadmap)